# Web Scraping: Extract different recurring classes and their content with Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to web scraping. I have a long website, which follows the following format: (class A being the title, class B subtitle, class C paragraphs of text)

```
<p class="A"> TEXT </p>
<p class="B"> TEXT </p>
<p class="C"> TEXT </p>
<p class="C"> TEXT </p>
<p class="C"> TEXT </p>
```

So basically both class A and class B appear once followed by one or multiple classes of C. Each class surrounds text. This pattern occurs more than 500 times, so I would really like to automate the extraction.

I want to create a CSV, which has the title text from class A in the first column, the subtitle text from class B in the second column and the text from class C in the third column.

I already figured out how to extract specific classes + text, for example:

```
soup.find_all('p', class_='A')
```

But the problem is that I have several class C texts associated with one class A and B. What would be the best way to handle this using Beautiful Soup (or if necessary another library). Many thanks!

Comment: so for the third column with many `C`s , what is your expected output?

Comment: Is the pattern for paragraphs `A B C C C A B C C C...` or `(A B C C C) (A B C C C) ...`. I mean, are the separated by any tags or are they continuous? The solution for the second case is pretty easy. But, if the pattern is like the first case, I'll post a different answer.

Comment: The annoying part is that they are continuous. :/ So I am unsure how to tie all the class C texts to the A and B class following right before.

Comment: @codekaizer:  So it would be class A) Title B) Subtitle C) all paragraphs directly following a title and subtitle (all class C texts directly following the pattern class A + class B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your HTML is somewhat like this:

```
<p class="A">Title1</p>
<p class="B">Subtitle1</p>
<p class="C">Text1</p>
<p class="C">Text1</p>
<p class="C">Text1</p>
<p class="A">Title2</p>
<p class="B">Subtitle2</p>
<p class="C">Text2</p>
<p class="C">Text2</p>
<p class="C">Text2</p>
```

What you can do here, is, loop over all the `<p>` tags with classes `A` or `B` or `C` with `find_all('p', class_=['A', 'B', 'C'])`.

The basic idea is, if we come across a `p` tag with `class="A"`, it means that the previous paragraph is finished and we've to add the strings into a CSV.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')  # html is the above html

title, subtitle, para = '', '', ''
for p in soup.find_all('p', class_=['A', 'B', 'C']):
    if p['class'][0] == 'A':
        if title:
            print(title, subtitle, para)  # Or add these values in CSV
        title = p.text
        para = ''
        continue
    if p['class'][0] == 'B':
        subtitle = p.text
        continue

    para += p.text + ' '

print(title, subtitle, para)  # Or add these values in CSV
```

Output:

```
Title1 Subtitle1 Text1 Text1 Text1 
Title2 Subtitle2 Text2 Text2 Text2
```

Comment: You are absolutely amazing!! Thank you for the quick response, this works like a charm! :)